# Create DynamoDB table with AWS CDK in Python with timestamp

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk

I'm trying to work with the AWS CDK for DynamoDB and am finding the documentation examples somewhat limited. I'm trying to create a specific DynamoDB table that gets a Timestamp attached to the table being created via AWS CDK. I tried finding examples of something that accomplishes this by referring to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_dynamodb/README.html) but am not able to find something close.

Below is my code that creates a table, but I need a timestamp to be attached to the table being created. I believe a working solution for what I am trying to do can consist of taking the value I have specified in "table_name" and concatenating the timeStamp variable with the value for "table_name". My python knowledge is somewhat limited. Any advice on how I can concatenate these values would be helpful. I think that should work.

```
from aws_cdk import (
core as cdk,
aws_dynamodb as dynamodb
)
from aws_cdk import core
from datetime import datetime


class CdkStack(cdk.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: cdk.Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        currentDate= dateTime.now()
        timeStamp= dateTime.timestamp(currentDate)
        dynamodbTable= dynamodb.Table(self,id='dynamodbTable',table_name='DynamoDbTableWithTimeStamp',partition_key=dynamodb.Attribute(name='id',type=dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING))
```

Comment: I also noticed that almost all your questions have answers, yet hardly any has been accepted. Accepting good answers is not only a good practice, but it reduces number of duplicates and increases chances for your questions to be actually answered.

Comment: My apologies. I've updated past questions.

Comment: Your question refers to some other websites, such as "finding examples of something", but you are not providing any links to them. Thus its difficult to see what you want to do.

Comment: Normally you would add timestamp when you `put_item` to your table.

Comment: I'm unclear about what you are trying to do.  Can you clarify what you mean by creating a table with a timestamp attached?  Do you want a table with a timestamp in the name?  Do you want to add timestamp to the items in your table?  Do you need a timestamp as part of your primary key?

Comment: Table with a timestamp of when it gets created in the name

Comment: FYI `CreationDateTime` is available as an attribute of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like simple string formatting is what you need:

```py
import time

...
table_name=f'DynamoDbTableWithTimeStamp_{int(time.time())}',
...
```

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time